# ESQL : Extracting Unique Elements from Recurring XML Segment

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am facing a challenge with ESQL code. I have an XML message that contains a recurring segment, and I need to extract unique values from a specific element within that segment. Following is the input XML message,

```
<MSG>
    <RecurringSegment>
        <Element>val1</Element>
    </RecurringSegment>
    <RecurringSegment>
        <Element>val2</Element>
    </RecurringSegment>
    <RecurringSegment>
        <Element>val1</Element>
    </RecurringSegment>
    <RecurringSegment>
        <Element>val3</Element>
    </RecurringSegment>
    <!-- ... (more recurring segments) ... -->
</MSG>
```

I have written the following ESQL code that iterates through the recurring segment, identifies unique values within the specific element (e.g., `<Element>`), and stores them in an output variable.

```
DECLARE uniqueVals ROW;
DECLARE i INTEGER 1;

FOR obj AS InputRoot.XMLNSC.MSG.RecurringSegment[] DO
    IF (NOT(CONTAINS(uniqueVals, obj.Element))) THEN
        SET uniqueVals.val[i] = obj.Element;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END IF;
END FOR;
```

But this is not working; need assistance with the ESQL code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The [CONTAINS function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=functions-contains-function) works only on string data types (BIT,BLOB,CHAR), not on ROW.

Following works good in case you have not too many unique values:

```
DECLARE occurences ROW;
DECLARE i INTEGER 1;

FOR obj AS InputRoot.XMLNSC.MSG.RecurringSegment[] DO
    DECLARE val CHAR obj.Element;
    IF COALESCE(occurences.{val}, 0) = 0 THEN
        SET occurences.{val} = 1;
    ELSE
        SET occurences.{val} = occurences.{val} + 1;
    END IF;
END FOR;

FOR obj AS occurences.*[] DO
    IF FIELDVALUE(obj) > 1 THEN
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Result
               NAME FIELDNAME(obj) VALUE FIELDVALUE(obj);
    END IF;
END FOR;
```

With your input this produces following result:

```
<Result>
  <val1>2</val1>
</Result>
```

This style of programming is not efficient for many unique values because `occurences.{val}` is not implemented by ESQL like a hash map.

Comment: But the output is supposed to be values 1, 2, 3

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe how exactly the output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to find the unique values. Adjusting Daniel Steinmann's answer a little...

```
DECLARE uniqueValues ROW;

FOR obj AS InputRoot.XMLNSC.MSG.RecurringSegment[] DO
    DECLARE val CHAR obj.Element;
    IF ( EXISTS(uniqueValues .{val}[]) ) THEN
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF uniqueValues TYPE Name NAME val 
    END IF;
END FOR;

SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Result[] = uniqueValues.*[];
```

Not able to test this, so I apologise for any logic/syntax errors.